# Using ImageViews instead of buttons in Android

Tags: android

I'm building my first android application.In my starting activity I want to use some ImageViews instead of buttons,These ImageViews are big tiles that their width should always match the parent Layout.I've drawn my imageViews to fit a normal mobile screen (4 inches I think ) how can i have them fit any device? like a 7 or 10 inch Tablet?

**EDIT:** Well sadly I used the fitCenter and didn't make any difference,that's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/home"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="My Classes"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"                
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
    android:text="Update Offline Data"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/configure"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />
```

Comment: Use `ImageButton` instead.

Comment: well i've tried what Hadi.A suggested.At first it worked but when i changed the layout_height to wrap_Content,because i could not place the view where i wanted.The image still didn't match the parent in width

Answer (score 2):

for fit the images you can use  android:scaleType="fitCenter" attribute in your control
like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSecurity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/security"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving them an absolute width, use the constant `match_parent` as `android:width`, that will always give them the same width as the parent view. The root view of an activity will have the same size as the screen with this width and/or height.

To also size an image in the ImageView to the correct size, use `fitCenter` as `android:scaletype`.

Comment: well i did, but instead expanding my view it just had it centered.

Answer (score 0):

If all  you're trying to do is getting the image to match the width of its container (and its container is matching the width of *its parent) then you should set the image as the background of the View, rather than its src.  I believe that will stretch it to fill the entire View, whatever its size is.